# Estimate number of clusters through EM in scikit-learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, artificial-intelligence, cluster-analysis, weka

I am trying to implement the cluster estimation method using EM found in [Weka](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/clusterers/EM.html), more precisely the following description:

> The cross validation performed to determine the number of clusters is
>   done in the following steps:
>
> 1. the number of clusters is set to 1
> 2. the training set is split randomly into 10 folds.
> 3. EM is performed 10 times using the 10 folds the usual CV way.
> 4. the loglikelihood is averaged over all 10 results.
> 5. if loglikelihood has increased the number of clusters is increased by 1 and the program continues at step  2.

My current implementation is as follows:

```
def estimate_n_clusters(X):
   "Find the best number of clusters through maximization of the log-likelihood from EM."
   last_log_likelihood = None
   kf = KFold(n_splits=10, shuffle=True)
   components = range(50)[1:]
   for n_components in components:
       gm = GaussianMixture(n_components=n_components)

       log_likelihood_list = []
       for train, test in kf.split(X):
           gm.fit(X[train, :])
           if not gm.converged_:
               raise Warning("GM not converged")
           log_likelihood = np.log(-gm.score_samples(X[test, :]))

           log_likelihood_list += log_likelihood.tolist()

       avg_log_likelihood = np.average(log_likelihood_list)

       if last_log_likelihood is None:
           last_log_likelihood = avg_log_likelihood
       elif avg_log_likelihood+10E-6 <= last_log_likelihood:
           return n_components
       last_log_likelihood = avg_log_likelihood
```

I am getting a similar number of clusters both trough Weka and my function, however, using the number of clusters `n_clusters` estimated by the function

```
gm = GaussianMixture(n_components=n_clusters).fit(X)
print(np.log(-gm.score(X)))
```

Results in NaN, since the `-gm.score(X)` yields negative results (about -2500). While Weka reports `Log likelihood: 347.16447`.

My guess is that the likelihood mentioned in step 4 of Weka is not the same as the one mentioned in the [function](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/a24c8b46/sklearn/mixture/base.py#L289)`score_samples()`.

Can anyone tell where I am getting something wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the documentation, `score` returns the average **log**likelihood. You don't want to use log-log, obviously.

Comment: Embarrassingly, that is true. Wha threw me off was that, during the iterations, I was getting `avg_log_likelihood` with values in the millions, so I was applying log thinking it should at least be in the ballpark of the last result, but apparently not. Simpling removing that log, I get a final likelihood around the same found by Weka. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, the fixed function looks like:

```
def estimate_n_clusters(X):
   "Find the best number of clusters through maximization of the log-likelihood from EM."
   last_log_likelihood = None
   kf = KFold(n_splits=10, shuffle=True)
   components = range(50)[1:]
   for n_components in components:
       gm = GaussianMixture(n_components=n_components)

       log_likelihood_list = []
       for train, test in kf.split(X):
           gm.fit(X[train, :])
           if not gm.converged_:
               raise Warning("GM not converged")
           log_likelihood = -gm.score_samples(X[test, :])

           log_likelihood_list += log_likelihood.tolist()

       avg_log_likelihood = np.average(log_likelihood_list)
       print(avg_log_likelihood)

       if last_log_likelihood is None:
           last_log_likelihood = avg_log_likelihood
       elif avg_log_likelihood+10E-6 <= last_log_likelihood:
           return n_components-1
       last_log_likelihood = avg_log_likelihood
```